# Why does running two websocket servers with different paths cause the client to get an "invalid frame header" and disconnect?

Tags: node.js, websocket

This is the server code

```js
import path from 'path';
import http from 'http';
import { dirname } from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import express from 'express';
import WebSocket from 'ws';
const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
const app = express();
console.log(__dirname)
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/v3client/html/botkill.html'));
})
let httpServer = http.createServer(app).listen(80, () => {
    console.log('listening');
});
global.hServer = httpServer;
let wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server: global.hServer, path: '/based' });
wss.on('listening', () => {
    console.log(`listening with path /based`);
});
function heartbeat() {
    this.isAlive = true;
}
wss.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('connected')
    socket.isAlive = true;
    socket.on('pong', heartbeat);
    socket.on('close', () => {
        console.log('disconnected')
    });
});
const pingPong = setInterval(() => {
    wss.clients.forEach((ws) => {
        if (ws.isAlive === false) return ws.terminate();
        ws.isAlive = false;
        ws.ping();
    });
}, 30000);
new WebSocket.Server({ server: global.hServer, path: '/notsobased' });
```

this is botkill.html

```html
<script>
    let ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost/based');
    ws.onopen = () => {
        console.log('open');
    };
    ws.onclose = async () => {
        console.log('disconnected');
    };
    ws.onerror = async (e) => {
        console.log(e, 'error');
    };
    ws.onmessage = function (e) {
        return false;
    };
</script>
```

When I open the webpage it immediately disconnects, but when I comment out the last line of the server code it gives me the error "invalid frame header". This is the smallest I could make the example, but I learned this recently when I tried to use two separate websocket servers on different paths, which seems to not work but I can't seem to figure out why. Also, it still immediately disconnects with https but it doesn't even have an error on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with a bit of searching for related topics I learned that the problem was that the websocket servers were both *attached* to the http server, rather than the http server itself handing connections to a websocket server.
by using the `http.Server.on('upgrade', ...)` and `Websocket.Server.handleUpgrade` with the two servers I got it working. Sorry for the inconvience!